# Aligning View with ImageView that has adjustViewBounds="true" does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

Did anybody encounter the situation when you have an ImageView with adjustViewBounds="true" and you need to align another view with it? My layout is working unpredictably:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/thumbnail"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/thumb"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/thumb">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great to not code that aligning.

Answer (score 0):

I changed RelativeLayout width and height to match_parent, and work for me. By the way what is  the point to align center the ImageView if it limited its size? It don't understand. What's the aim? Can you post a wireframe?